# Insert into in Gridview. Makes insert on refresh..asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, insert, refresh

I have a customer Gridview with the possibility to make an insert of a new customer in the footertemplate.

When i press my insert button i make a Redirect to the same page and i can see my new customer in the gridview.

What a noticed was that when i make a refresh directly on the page it adds the same customer again. That's really strange for me because after my Redirect my requiredfields like firstname lastname and so on are all empty of course but still the page grabs the values from before and makes another insert.

Why is it like that and how can i solve this Problem?

aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="3" DataKeyNames="CustID" DataSourceID="Event" GridLines="Horizontal" ShowFooter="True" AllowPaging="True" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#E7E7FF" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="CustID">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CustID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CustID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ValidationGroup="INSERT" OnClick="lbInsert_Click"  ID="lbInsert" runat="server" >Insert</asp:LinkButton>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Anrede" SortExpression="Gender">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Gender" DataValueField="Gender" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Gender") %>'>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EventConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Gender] FROM [Customer]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Gender") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <div style="text-align: center;"><asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text="Anrede"></asp:Label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGender" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem>Anrede Auswählen</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Herr</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Frau</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvInsGender" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Anrede ist ein Pflichtfeld"
                    ControlToValidate="ddlGender" ValidationGroup="INSERT" Text="*" ForeColor="Red" InitialValue="Anrede Auswählen">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </div>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="LastName">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEdLastName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Name ist ein Pflichtfeld"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox2" Text="*" ForeColor="Red">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <div style="text-align: center;"><asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label></div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvInsLastName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Name ist ein Pflichtfeld"
                    ControlToValidate="txtLastName" ValidationGroup="INSERT" Text="*" ForeColor="Red">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vorname" SortExpression="FirstName">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEdFirstName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="VorName ist ein Pflichtfeld"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox3" Text="*" ForeColor="Red">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <div style="text-align: center;"><asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Text="Vorname"></asp:Label></div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvInsFirstName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="VorName ist ein Pflichtfeld"
                    ControlToValidate="txtFirstName" ValidationGroup="INSERT" Text="*" ForeColor="Red">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Strasse" SortExpression="Street">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Street") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEdStreet" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Strasse ist ein Pflichtfeld"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox4" Text="*" ForeColor="Red">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Street") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <div style="text-align: center;"><asp:Label ID="Label16" runat="server" Text="Strasse"></asp:Label></div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtStreet" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvInsStreet" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Strasse ist ein Pflichtfeld"
                    ControlToValidate="txtStreet" ValidationGroup="INSERT" Text="*" ForeColor="Red">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="House Nr" SortExpression="HouseNr">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("HouseNr") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEdHouseNr" runat="server" ErrorMessage="House Nr ist ein Pflichtfeld"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox5" Text="*" ForeColor="Red">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("HouseNr") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <div style="text-align: center;"><asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server" Text="House Nr"></asp:Label></div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtHouseNr" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvInsHouseNr" runat="server" ErrorMessage="House Nr ist ein Pflichtfeld"
                    ControlToValidate="txtHouseNr" ValidationGroup="INSERT" Text="*" ForeColor="Red">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PLZ" SortExpression="Zip">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Zip") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEdZip" runat="server" ErrorMessage="PLZ ist ein Pflichtfeld"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox6" Text="*" ForeColor="Red">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Zip") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <div style="text-align: center;"><asp:Label ID="Label18" runat="server" Text="PLZ"></asp:Label></div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtZip" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvInsZip" runat="server" ErrorMessage="PLZ ist ein Pflichtfeld"
                    ControlToValidate="txtZip" ValidationGroup="INSERT" Text="*" ForeColor="Red">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ort" SortExpression="City">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("City") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEdCity" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Ort ist ein Pflichtfeld"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox7" Text="*" ForeColor="Red">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("City") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <div style="text-align: center;"><asp:Label ID="Label19" runat="server" Text="Ort"></asp:Label></div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvInsCity" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Ort ist ein Pflichtfeld"
                    ControlToValidate="txtCity" ValidationGroup="INSERT" Text="*" ForeColor="Red">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Telefon" SortExpression="Phone">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Phone") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Phone") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <div style="text-align: center;"><asp:Label ID="Label20" runat="server" Text="Telefon"></asp:Label></div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="E-mail" SortExpression="Email">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Email") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Email") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <div style="text-align: center;"><asp:Label ID="Label21" runat="server" Text="E-mail"></asp:Label></div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Firma" SortExpression="Company">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Company") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Company") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <div style="text-align: center;"><asp:Label ID="Label22" runat="server" Text="Firma"></asp:Label></div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompany" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Active">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Active" DataValueField="Active" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Active") %>'>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EventConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Active] FROM [Customer]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Active") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <div style="text-align: center;"><asp:Label ID="Label23" runat="server" Text="Status"></asp:Label></div>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlActive" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem>Status Auswählen</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Aktiv</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Passiv</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvInsActive" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Status ist ein Pflichtfeld"
                    ControlToValidate="ddlActive" ValidationGroup="INSERT" Text="*" ForeColor="Red" InitialValue="Status Auswählen">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#B5C7DE" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#B5C7DE" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F4F4FD" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#5A4C9D" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D8D8F0" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#3E3277" />
</asp:GridView>
</div>
<asp:ValidationSummary ValidationGroup="INSERT" ID="ValidationSummary1" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" />
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary2" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" />
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="Event" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EventConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Customer] WHERE [CustID] = @CustID" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Customer] ([Gender], [LastName], [FirstName], [Street], [HouseNr], [Zip], [City], [Phone], [Email], [Company], [Active]) VALUES (@Gender, @LastName, @FirstName, @Street, @HouseNr, @Zip, @City, @Phone, @Email, @Company, @Active)" SelectCommand="SELECT [CustID], [Gender], [LastName], [FirstName], [Street], [HouseNr], [Zip], [City], [Phone], [Email], [Company], [Active] FROM [Customer]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Customer] SET [Gender] = @Gender, [LastName] = @LastName, [FirstName] = @FirstName, [Street] = @Street, [HouseNr] = @HouseNr, [Zip] = @Zip, [City] = @City, [Phone] = @Phone, [Email] = @Email, [Company] = @Company, [Active] = @Active WHERE [CustID] = @CustID">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustID" Type="Decimal" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Gender" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Street" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="HouseNr" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Zip" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="City" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Phone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Company" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Active" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Gender" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Street" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="HouseNr" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Zip" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="City" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Phone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Company" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Active" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustID" Type="Decimal" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void lbInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Event.InsertParameters["Gender"].DefaultValue = ((DropDownList)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlGender")).SelectedValue;
        Event.InsertParameters["LastName"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtLastName")).Text;
        Event.InsertParameters["FirstName"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtFirstName")).Text;
        Event.InsertParameters["Street"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtStreet")).Text;
        Event.InsertParameters["HouseNr"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtHouseNr")).Text;
        Event.InsertParameters["Zip"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtZip")).Text;
        Event.InsertParameters["City"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCity")).Text;
        Event.InsertParameters["Phone"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtPhone")).Text;
        Event.InsertParameters["Email"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtEmail")).Text;
        Event.InsertParameters["Company"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCompany")).Text;
        Event.InsertParameters["Active"].DefaultValue = ((DropDownList)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlActive")).SelectedValue;

        Event.Insert();
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            var dr = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

            if (dr["CustID"].ToString() == "60" || dr["CustID"].ToString() == "62")
            {
                e.Row.Enabled = false;  //OR dr.Enabled = false;
                //DISABLED Controls only     
                //((TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TextBox1")).Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one method to bind the Grid and while you insert the data into grid than just call this method to bind grid...Try this...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Where and how can i do that? Im really new to this. Can you Hand me some code?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void BindGrid()
{
    //Your Code For Fill the Grid...Possibly If You Use Database than Fired Query to fetch data and fill Grid...
}

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var dr = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

        if (dr["CustID"].ToString() == "60" || dr["CustID"].ToString() == "62")
        {
            e.Row.Enabled = false;  //OR dr.Enabled = false;
            //DISABLED Controls only     
            //((TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TextBox1")).Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    BindGrid();
}
```

Comment: I don't have any code to fill the Gridview in codebehind. Can i somehow solve this without creating the Gridview in codebehind?

Answer (score 0):

What you all need is to use

```
Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
```

use it at the bottom of your button click event code

```
 protected void lbInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Event.InsertParameters["Gender"].DefaultValue = ((DropDownList)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlGender")).SelectedValue;
        Event.InsertParameters["LastName"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtLastName")).Text;
        Event.InsertParameters["FirstName"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtFirstName")).Text;
        Event.InsertParameters["Street"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtStreet")).Text;
        Event.InsertParameters["HouseNr"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtHouseNr")).Text;
        Event.InsertParameters["Zip"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtZip")).Text;
        Event.InsertParameters["City"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCity")).Text;
        Event.InsertParameters["Phone"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtPhone")).Text;
        Event.InsertParameters["Email"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtEmail")).Text;
        Event.InsertParameters["Company"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCompany")).Text;
        Event.InsertParameters["Active"].DefaultValue = ((DropDownList)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlActive")).SelectedValue;

        Event.Insert();
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
    }
```